# Automatic Counting is skipping even numbers.... MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, view

In my view I have a code in my view

View:

```
 <div id="batch_payments">
        @foreach (var batchPayment in Model.BatchPayments)
        {
            if(batchPayment.CustomerIdEntered != null)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("BatchPaymentAdd", batchPayment);
            }
        }
    </div>
```

**Partial View:**

```
<span class="batch_payment_index white">@String.Format("{0}.", Model.BatchPaymentIndex)</span>
```

Model:

```
public class BatchPaymentViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public int BatchPaymentId { get; set; }
    public string BatchTypeId { get; set; }
    public int BatchPaymentIndex { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public string CustomerIdEntered { get; set; }
    public string RoutingNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string CheckNumber { get; set; }
    public string CreditCardNumber { get; set; }
    public string ReceiptNumber { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BatchPaymentSplitViewModel> PaymentSplits { get; set; }
    private bool _isBatchEditable;
    public bool IsBatchEditable { get {return _isBatchEditable; } set { UpdateIsBatchEditable(value); } }
    public bool IsThisEditable { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public BatchPaymentViewModel()
    {
        PaymentSplits = new List<BatchPaymentSplitViewModel>();
        PaymentSplits.Add(new BatchPaymentSplitViewModel());
        BatchPaymentIndex = 0;
        IsBatchEditable = true;
        IsThisEditable = true;
        Status = "Unknown";
    }
    public BatchPaymentViewModel(int index)
    {
        PaymentSplits = new List<BatchPaymentSplitViewModel>();
        PaymentSplits.Add(new BatchPaymentSplitViewModel());
        BatchPaymentIndex = index;
        IsBatchEditable = true;
        IsThisEditable = true;
        Status = "Unknown";
    }
    public BatchPaymentViewModel(BatchPayment batchPayment, int index = 0)
    {
        BatchPaymentId = batchPayment.BatchPaymentId;
        BatchTypeId = batchPayment.Batch.BatchTypeId;
        BatchPaymentIndex = index;
        Amount = batchPayment.BatchPaymentSplits.Select(i => i.Amount).First();
        CustomerIdEntered = batchPayment.BatchPaymentSplits.Select(i => i.CustomerIdEntered).First();
        RoutingNumber = batchPayment.RoutingNumber;
        AccountNumber = batchPayment.AccountNumber;
        CheckNumber = batchPayment.CheckNumber;
        CreditCardNumber = batchPayment.CreditCardNumber;
        ReceiptNumber = batchPayment.UniqueId;
        Status = batchPayment.BatchPaymentStatus.Text;
        PaymentSplits = new List<BatchPaymentSplitViewModel>();
        foreach (var split in batchPayment.BatchPaymentSplits.OrderBy(bp => bp.BatchPaymentId))
        {
            PaymentSplits.Add(new BatchPaymentSplitViewModel(split));
        }
        if (PaymentSplits.Count == 0)
        {
            PaymentSplits.Add(new BatchPaymentSplitViewModel());
        }
        IsBatchEditable = batchPayment.Batch.IsEditable;
        IsThisEditable = batchPayment.IsEditable;
    }
```

all this does is add a number to my row that is displayed in my view.  However, I have some rows that are hidden.  These numbers are still being counted so my rows are being displayed as 1,3,5,7 etc.

Edit: If I remove the If statement in my view it counts correctly. so It's still counting rows that aren't applicable.

How do I get this code to ignore the hidden rows and count 1,2,3,4 etc.

Comment: Any chance you could add a boolean IsHidden to the object? Then just get the items that arent hidden?

Comment: Please add code surrounding this line of code. Like a loop.

Comment: where are you incrementing the `Model.BatchPaymentIndex`?

Comment: You could filter out hidden ones from controller itself as Chris suggested, or you could have a loop variable that increments only when a valid row comes.

Comment: what is `BatchPaymentIndex` and what does your model look like?

Answer (score 0):

All your code does is display what is stored in `Model.BatchPaymentIndex` - you will need to rework you models and add in something like a `BatchPaymentDisplayIndex` and rework these numbers as rows are shown and hidden.

Without seeing the code for your model there isn't much more help that can be given.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.  Your advice lead me to the index code, which someone else had written so I wasn't looking for it.  and came up with a solution

```
if (batchPayment.BatchPaymentSplits.Select(i => i.CustomerIdEntered).First() != null)
{
    BatchPaymentIndex = (index + 1) / 2;
}
else
{
    BatchPaymentIndex = index;
}
```